# How do I permute a set of points with restrictions?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I am trying to permute a set of points in java with the restriction that all points in an odd position n cannot appear before the point in position (n-1) i.e ,given 2 point 1 and 2 ,2 cannot appear before 1 in any of the permutations and given points 1,2,3 & 4 , the set of expected permutations are:

```
1,2,3,4
1,3,2,4
1,3,4,2
3,1,2,4
3,4,1,2
3,1,4,2
```

I currently have the following code for finding permutations:

```
static void permute(int[] a, int k,int[] p) {
    if (k == a.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    else {
        int temp;
        for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
                permute(a, k + 1,p);
                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
            else{
                if(k > p[i]){
                    temp = a[k];
                    a[k] = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp;
                    permute(a, k + 1,p);
                    temp = a[k];
                    a[k] = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but my current output is :

```
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 4 3
 1 3 2 4
 1 3 4 2
 1 4 3 2
 1 4 2 3
 3 2 1 4
 3 2 4 1
 3 1 2 4
 3 1 4 2
 3 4 1 2
 3 4 2 1
```

Any help would be really appreciated :-)

Comment: These kind of exercises are well documented and are all solved by applying backtracking. You can take a look at this http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~cscie119/lectures/recursion.pdf where you will find a template for backtracking algorithms at page 18 as they all look the same. More generalized versions also wrap data in nodes to make it easy to reuse.

Comment: Can you explain the rule more precisely? If 'all points in an odd position n cannot appear before the point in position (n-1)' how can 3 (which is at an odd position (3) appear before 2? Why is the rule only applied to '1' and '2' if your example has the numbers 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @MrSmith42 : He might have meant "even"? So that 2 cannot appear before 1, and 4 cannot appear before 3.

Comment: @MrSmith42, sorry I was counting from 0 as I'm using arrays

Comment: One idea is  that store the index of each number in an array initially (Let's say it array_of_index) and when you are swapping elements of the array to  get each permutation, swap its respective index in array_of_index also and when you get the permutation with your code , validate the permutation by iterating through the array_of_index on the basis of the special given condition.

Answer (score 2):

You may first find all permutations and then filter only those where restriction is respected. Below an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PermutationsExample {

    static int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> allPermutationList = getAllPermutations(arr); 
        System.out.println("All permutations are :");
        System.out.println(allPermutationList);
        System.out.println("");

        List<List<Integer>> subPermutationList = getRestrictedPermutations(allPermutationList);
        System.out.println("Permutations with restrictions are:");
        System.out.println(subPermutationList);
    }

    // see http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/leetcode-permutations-java/   for further info

    public static  List<List<Integer>> getAllPermutations(int[] num) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new ArrayList<>()); 
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            List<List<Integer>> current = new ArrayList<>();
                for (List<Integer> l : result) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < l.size()+1; j++) {
                        l.add(j, num[i]);
                        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(l);
                        current.add(temp);
                        l.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            result = new ArrayList<>(current);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> getRestrictedPermutations(List<List<Integer>> listofList){
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<Integer> list: listofList){                       
            if(isRestrictionRespected(list)){
               result.add(list);
            }            
        }        
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isRestrictionRespected(List<Integer> list){
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i+=2 ) {            
                if(list.indexOf(arr[i])<list.indexOf(arr[i-1])){
                 result = false;
                 break;
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a recursive approach?

Simply cut off the recursion branch as soon as your condition get violated.